# Cannot play video stream in two instances of VLC player

Tags: libvlc

We are using libvlc in our Linux application to play an RTP MJPEG stream from an IP camera. We'd like to have two libvlc_media_players playing the video, one playing a full image in a GtkDrawingArea, and another playing a cropped/resized portion of the video (pseudo-zoom) in another GtkDrawingArea.
The problem is, only one of the media players is working. It seems whichever instance connects first, is blocking the second instance from binding to the port.

We need a way replicate the traffic to two ports may be or any other advice?

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 2 ways to achieve what you want, depending on the exact result you need.

While you can only call `libvlc_new` once, and so have only 1 `libvlc` instance in your app running at all times, you may create as many media players as you want from `libvlc`. They will be independant though, so if you need exact sync, this isn't what you want to use.

One other way would be to duplicate the video output, using for example

```
Clone video filter (clone)
 Duplicate your video to multiple windows and/or video output modules
      --clone-count=<integer>    Number of clones
          Number of video windows in which to clone the video.
      --clone-vout-list=<string> Video output modules
          You can use specific video output modules for the clones. Use a
          comma-separated list of modules.
```

https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help

with `libvlc_media_add_option` (replace `--` with `:` when using this function).

You can also use `--sout` with `#duplicate` as well. https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/

Depending on the way you choose, VLC might create a new Window by itself, which you might have to grab and incorporate in your app.